# How can I initialize an OrderedDictionary from a regular Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, collections, type-conversion, ordereddictionary

Apples [swift-collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) package provides an alternative to a `Dictionary` type which guarantees to **keep** (not *bring*) its key-value pairs in order (unlike the regular `Dictionary`  type). But how can I turn an instance of type `Dictionary` into an instance of type `OrderedDictionary` for later re-ordering?

For example, how would it work for this dict:

```swift
let regularDict: [String: String] = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
// => EITHER {key2=>value2, key1=>value1} OR {key1=>value1, key2=>value2}

let orderedDict: OrderedDictionary<String, String> = .init(/* ??? */)
```

I am aware that `orderedDict` will have a **random order** of key-value entries at first, that's fine for me, I just need an `OrderedDictionary` instance so any future changes to the order I make don't get lost. I just want to know how to initialize it from a `Dictionary` in a way that is performant and makes sure the keys stay connected to the correct values.

Comment: What does 'keep ... in order' mean?  The order they were added (and then what happens if you supply non-ordered data to initialise)?  Numeric order?  Alphabetical Order?  By a custom closure or a standard sort?

Comment: There is no way to accomplish what you are asking. Dictionary is an unordered collection. There is no way to predict what will be your ordered dictionary order if you get the values through a dictionary.

Comment: Using a dictionary to initialize your `OrderedDictionary` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: BTW AFAIK `OrderedDictionary` conforms to `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral ` and would preserve the desired order.  That is the property to initialize your ordered dictionary `let orderedDic: OrderedDictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]` or using another ordered collection like sequence, collection or Array. There is no way to predict the order of a dictionary or a set.

Comment: @flanker The `OrderedDictionary` in swift-collections doesn't "sort" anything, it's basically an array of key-value pairs that has some useful similarities to `Dictionary` that it can be exchanged for that.

Comment: @LeoDabus I know that `Dictionary` is an unordered collection. I never asked for a "sorted dictionary", I only asked for initializing an "ordered dictionary", the sorting comes after, but the question is focused on just the instance initialization as that's not documented anywhere.

Comment: @LeoDabus I know that `OrderedDictionary` conforms to `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral`, but in my case I'm decoding a `Dictionary` from a `.plist` file (can't decode into `OrderedDictionary` since it doesn't support dynamic keys, see here: https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/issues/135) and then I want to keep them in an ordered list, where I sort by the keys at first, then let the user re-order to their liking. I think your judgement of if this can makes sense or not was too early. Just asking me for the use case would have been more friendly.

Comment: @Jeehut just edit your answer and pass your dictionary sorted into an array of tuples instead of passing a dictionary shuffled

Comment: @LeoDabus But that would be the incorrect answer to a question which is not asking for any kind of specific sorting, but instead is just asking for the initializer. ;) You're still thinking of the "ordered" collection as a "sorted" collection. But an array is also not "sorted", but it's "ordered". Think of my question like I'm asking for how to convert a Set type into an Array type without sorting.

Comment: This is just for future readers to understand that passing a dictionary won't preserve the order you used to initialize your dictionary.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have already edited both the question & answer to make this more clear. Please check.

Comment: @LeoDabus I just added comments to make it even more clear, hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`init(uniqueKeys:values:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Sources/OrderedCollections/OrderedDictionary/OrderedDictionary%2BInitializers.swift#L129-L163) with the regular dictionaries' `keys` and `values`:

```swift
let regularDict = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
// => EITHER {key2=>value2, key1=>value1} OR {key1=>value1, key2=>value2}

var orderedDict = OrderedDictionary<String, String>(
  uniqueKeys: regularDict.keys, 
  values: regularDict.values
)
// => EITHER {key2=>value2, key1=>value1} OR {key1=>value1, key2=>value2}
```

This will not magically sort anything though, the resulting `orderedDict` will have key-value entries of same random order as the `regularDict`. But any future changes to the order will be persistent. For example, you could order by keys of a type conforming to `Comparable` like this:

```swift
orderedEntries.sort(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
// => {key1=>value1, key2=>value2}
```

Comment: But this will create an ordered dictionary with whatever random order the old dictionary had. Or is that not relevant for the question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Not relevant for my question, I was very specifically just asking for how to initialize an `OrderedDictionary` with a `Dictionary` I have available. That this will result in random order at first was clear to me, but you may be right that I should have been more explicit about that. I will edit both the questions and answer to make this more clear.